# Kendo UI Grid: How to change cell text based on a bit value

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid which displays some records and users have the ability to edit the records. If a record is set to IsReadOnly then that row controls are disabled meaning users can only read it but no edits. 
Below are different columns of grid.

```
  columns: [
                { field: "Id", hidden: true },
                { field: "DisplayValue", title: "Description" },
                { field: "DisplayOrder", hidden: true },
                { field: "IsActive", hidden: true },
                { field: "IsReadOnly", title: "Read Only"},
                { template: kendo.template($("#activate-command-template").html()), width: 93 }
            ]
```

If IsReadOnly comes true when I want to display a message for that records saying "Contact IT to make this row editable" and if its false then I would display an empty string. How Do I achieve this in dataBound event ?
Below is my dataBound event:

```
if (adminView.viewModel.get("selectedControllerItemName") == "IntakeReferralMethod") {
                        var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();
                        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
                            var currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
                            if (gridData[i].IsReadOnly == true) {
                                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                                var activateButton = $(currenRow).find(".k-button").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

**My problem:** How do I set the text for the records to "Contact IT" if IsReadOnly is true and set the text to empty string when IsReadOnly is false?

Please let me know if some clarification is needed. I been searching for hours and cannot find anything which can help me understand how to manipulate text on grid when certain bit field is true or false.

Comment: Where do you want to display the message?

Comment: On the ReadOnly column. It would have text "Contact IT" which has a true value for ReadOnly and a blank " " text for records which have false for ReadOnly @whipdancer

Answer (score 0):

In each field where you want the "Contact IT" text to appear, you can add a template. Kind of like what you have in the last field, but you can bind the template to the data in the row and put a condition that checks the data and displays one string or the other. It sounds more complicated than it is. I'm not in front of a computer but from memory here goes an example:

{
//field info...
template: '#: isReadOnly ? "Contact IT" : "" '
}

The #: is what binds the template to the current row's data. The question mark and colon form an inline if-then-else statement. isReadOnly is one of the fields in your row.

Give it a try and post back with the results

Comment: So initially I went with the below template:   { field: "IsReadOnly", title: "Read Only", template: "#= (IsReadOnly) ? 'Read Only(Contact IT to make this record editable)' : '' #" } . This showed me the desired results. But when I was trying to add new record to grid it would blow up saying "IsReadOnly" is undefined. Which is why I am doing down the approach of setting it in dataBound event.

Comment: I see... But there are other options too. In your IsReadOnly field definition you could add the property defaultValue:false (or true, whatever you need), or in the template I posted, do (typeof IsReadOnly != "undefined" && IsReadonly == true) ? "Contact IT" : ""

Comment: Did you give this a try? (What I suggested in my last comment) did it work?